# Which Active Directory's attribute corresponds to the "bind_password" parameter of the ldap_bind function in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, active-directory, ldap

I am creating an API for registration and authentication by Active Directory.

When registering, I use the "userPassword" field to store the password.

```
$user = new User([
    'cn' => $full_name,
    'userPassword' => $password,
    'samaccountname' => $username,
    'mail' => $email
]);

$user->inside(config('ldap.connections.default.base_dn'));

$user->save();
```

Registration works fine.
But at the time of authentication, the Active Directory does not recognize the provided password:

```
$user = User::where('samaccountname', '=', $username)->firstOrFail(); // all is good here. print_r($user) shows user details

if (Container::getDefaultConnection()->auth()->attempt($user['distinguishedname'], $password)) {

    // returns a response to the user
    return \response()->json(
        new UserResource($user), 200
    );

} else {

    return \response()->json(
        [
            'message' => 'invalid credentials or user not exists.'
        ], 403
    );
}
```

Can someone help me.

Comment: Which package are you using for this LDAP? and can you try: `if (Container::getDefaultConnection()->auth()->attempt($user->distinguishedname, $user->userPassword))`

Comment: I'm using LdapRecord. From here `https://ldaprecord.com/`

Answer (score 1):

Using plain stored password won't work, there are some encoding which need to be carried out but there's a mutator `unicodePwd` that will handle it for you. Try

```
$user = new User([
    'cn' => $full_name,
    'unicodePwd ' => $password,
    'samaccountname' => $username,
    'mail' => $email
]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Now I'm getting the following error message: `ldap_add(): Add: Server is unwilling to perform`

Comment: Did you set enable flag on it? (512)

Comment: Yes but no change. Maybe I must see with my system administrator.

Comment: I have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

The attribute used to set the password of an account is [`unicodePwd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/6e803168-f140-4d23-b2d3-c3a8ab5917d2). This attribute can only be set, not read.

There are some strict requirements about the format of what you put there, which are described in the Microsoft documentation. However, the LdapRecord library handles that for you, according to [their documentation](https://ldaprecord.com/docs/active-directory/users/#creation):

> The password string you set on the users `unicodePwd` attribute is automatically encoded, you do not need to encode it yourself.

Their example on how to create an AD user looks like this:

```php
$user = (new User)->inside('ou=Users,dc=local,dc=com');

$user->cn = 'John Doe';
$user->samaccountname = 'jdoe';
$user->unicodePwd = 'SecretPassword';
$user->userPrincipalName = 'jdoe@acme.org';

$user->save();

// Enable the user.
$user->userAccountControl = 512;

try {
    $user->save();
} catch (\LdapRecord\LdapRecordException $e) {
    // Failed saving user.
}
```

Comment: Same result. I contacted my system administrator to see if there are restrictions in the active directory. I'll be back.

Comment: If your old way of using `userPassword` works, then use that. But you will have to set `userAccountControl` to `512` (`NORMAL_ACCOUNT`) otherwise the account will be disabled. All accounts are created disabled unless you specify otherwise.